# How to get specific result from api in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am working on web application which list all platform games. For this I also have api. Api format is like this:

```
{
      "title":"Doom 3: BFG Edition",
      "platform":"Xbox 360",
      "score":7.6,
      "genre":"RPG",
      "editors_choice":"N"
   }
```

Suppose I parse only pc(platform) result from api. How can  i parse it from api in jquery??

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to parse the json response then you can do it like below

```js
x = {
    "title":"Doom 3: BFG Edition",
    "platform":"PC",
    "score":7.6,
    "genre":"RPG",
    "editors_choice":"N"
}

console.log("Title : " + x.title);
console.log("platform : " + x.platform);
console.log("score : " + x.score);
console.log("genre : " + x.genre);
console.log("editors choice : " + x.editors_choice);

if(x.platform == "PC"){
    alert("game is pc platform !");
}

var data = [ 
    {"Game": "Gears Of War", "PlatForm": "PC"}, 
    {"Game": "NFS Most Wanted", "PlatForm": "X-Box"}, 
    {"Game": "xyz", "PlatForm": "PS3"}
];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].Game + data[i].PlatForm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No suppose i have too much data.So i want only that data which user clicked.Suppose user click pc tab so response from api should only be that objects which have platform pc.

Comment: then you can loop through that data. wait am adding example

Comment: @Andrew if you want the response from the server to only have results with a certain platform, you need to filter it out server-side, it's not a thing you can do client-side.

Comment: Also, in case you need this information, to parse a string as JSON, use the javascript method `JSON.parse`, e.g. `var x = JSON.parse(serverResponse)`

Comment: @Andrew, also take a look at [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter); `JSON.parse` and then `filter` will do the purpose I presume.

Answer (score 0):

```
var items=  {
      "title":"Doom 3: BFG Edition",
      "platform":"Xbox 360",
      "score":7.6,
      "genre":"RPG",
      "editors_choice":"N"
   }
   console.log(items.platform);
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, it is always better if you can explain why your answer solves the question.  This helps when others view the answer to understand what has changed and why it should be done this way.